# customizing the webcalendar in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to customize the asp:Calendar-Element the following way:

1) Each day has a dropwndown list wiith 6-7 phrases like (out of office, on holidays) and so on. and depending on which option you click, the color of that da changes. also, the selected optin should be saved to a database.

2) only certain users should be able to look at past months. For all other users, there should be no button for selecting previous months.

Is that possible with this calendar? Has anyone ever modified it in this way and can give me some tips? Or do I need to create such a calendar myself?

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? If yes, show us the code please.

Comment: nope, nothing really yet, except adding the asp:calendar-element to the page and modifying it in the properties-window, so I changed the width, some colors etc. The problem is, Ive only developed in asp.net and c# for three days :D I usually program in Java or PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes can do with your asp.net calendar but you have do by customize your asp.net calendar with CSS as well as jQuery. I had also implemented in past with asp.net calendar. Below code is just for your help.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Calendar {border:none;}
    .Calendar img{ border:none;}
    .Calendar .Title {background-color:#7D9459;background-image:url(../Images/title_bg.gif);border: 1px solid black;border-bottom-width: 0px;}
    .Calendar .Title td {font-family:verdana;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:White;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;}
    .Calendar .DayHeader {background-color:#E3E0CD;background-image:url(../Images/header_bg.gif);color:#504C39;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;text-align:center;border-top:solid 1px #FFFFFF; border-left:solid 1px #FFFFFF; border-bottom:solid 1px #ACA899;border-right:solid 1px #C6C1AC; padding: 4px; font-weight:normal;}
    .Calendar .Day {width:90px;  height:70px;  text-align:center; vertical-align:top; font-family:Verdana; font-size:11px; color:Black; background-color:#FFFFFF;  border:solid 1px #C6C1AC; padding:2px;}
    .Calendar .OtherMonthDay {background-color:#F5F3E5;}
</style>

<asp:Calendar ID="MeetingCalendar" runat="server" CssClass="Calendar" TitleStyle-BackColor="Transparent"
                                CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0px" Width="" DayNameFormat="Full" OnDayRender="MeetingCalendar_DayRender"
                                TitleStyle-CssClass="Title" DayHeaderStyle-CssClass="DayHeader" DayStyle-CssClass="Day"   
                                DayStyle-Width="90px" OtherMonthDayStyle-CssClass="Day OtherMonthDay" NextMonthText="<img src='../Images/next_wht.gif' alt='' style='float:right;' />"
                                PrevMonthText="<img src='../Images/prev_wht.gif' alt='' style='float:left;'/>" 
                                onvisiblemonthchanged="MeetingCalendar_VisibleMonthChanged">
                            </asp:Calendar>


protected void MeetingCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            string dayNumber = e.Day.Date.Day.ToString();
            e.Cell.Text = dayNumber + "<br />"; 

            e.Cell.Text += "<div align='center'>";
            e.Cell.Text += "    <a href='DailyMeetings.aspx?id=10' title='Day has meeting(s) scheduled.'>";
            e.Cell.Text += "            <img src='../Images/meeting.gif' height='25' width='25' alt='' border='0' />";
            e.Cell.Text += "        </a>";
            e.Cell.Text += "</div>";
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Naresh! That's going to be a great help!